# YouTube image overlay - Javascript not executing for two elements

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I am effectively trying to overlay an image over a YouTube video and when you click the image the YouTube video plays.

I am having an issue with the Javascript as I believe I cannot call the same ID. I am getting pretty tied up with it so any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width:423px; height:336px;">

<div id="ytapiplayer2" style="display:none;">
<object width="423" height="336"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/cbP2N1BQdYc&rel=0&autoplay=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/cbP2N1BQdYc&rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="423" height="336"></embed></object></p>
</div>
<p><img src="http://placekitten.com/500/200" id="imageID" /><br />

</div>

<div style="width:423px; height:336px;">

<div id="ytapiplayer2" style="display:none;">
<object width="423" height="336"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/cbP2N1BQdYc&rel=0&autoplay=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/cbP2N1BQdYc&rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="423" height="336"></embed></object></p>
</div>
<p><img src="http://placekitten.com/500/199" id="imageID" /><br />

</div>

  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
$('#imageID').click(function() {
$('#ytapiplayer2').show();
$('#imageID').hide();
});
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: ID should be unique for your DOM elements. Use a class if it needs to be applied to multiple elements. Do you want a solution where it is class instead?

Comment: Hi Moriarty, yes that would be amazing and probably a little better too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

HTML:

```
<div style="width:423px; height:336px;" id="test">

    <div class="ytapiplayer2" style="display:none;">
        <object width="423" height="336">
            <param name="movie"             value="http://www.youtube.com/v/cbP2N1BQdYc&rel=0&autoplay=1">
            </param>
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
            </param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
            </param>
            <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/cbP2N1BQdYc&rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="423" height="336"></embed></object>
</div>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/500/200" class="imageID" /><br />

</div>

<div style="width:423px; height:336px;">

<div class="ytapiplayer2" style="display:none;">
<object width="423" height="336"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/cbP2N1BQdYc&rel=0&autoplay=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/cbP2N1BQdYc&rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="423" height="336"></embed></object>
</div>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/500/199" class="imageID" /><br />

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.imageID').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.ytapiplayer2').show();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: That's amazing - Thanks very much Moriarty!

Comment: Sorry to go back to this, I am having an issue where I am having to enter the jquery.min.js line twice in order for it to work, which is REALLY strange. I've not see that before?

Comment: It is probably because the page hasn't loaded before it executes the script. Edited the answer. Provide more information if the problem persists.

Comment: That did the job. I think there are some heavy external .JS files being called in the header which is causing the issue. Thanks for this!